# 68k macintosh lowmem system globals

Tags: apple-macintosh, mac-os-classic, operating-system

While digging through a classic Mac 68k disassembly I got to the point where I need to know more about the "Boot Globals" residing in lowmem's system global variables.

*BootGlobPtr* lives at $DDC, that's for sure, and it points to different locations on different machines - that's what a pointer was meant for.

So far so good, but what's the structure of the data living there? Here's some sample of its usage:

```
MOVEA.L BootGlobPtr,A1  ; $DDC points to $04FFFFE4 on a SE/30, $04FFFFF4 on IIci
ADDA.L  -16(A1),A1     
MOVE.L  20(A1),D0
```

Besides [some Emulator source](https://github.com/cebix/macemu/blob/master/cxmon/src/mon_lowmem.cpp), I can't find anything on the web providing more insight... Does anyone in here have a hint or can remember where to look it up?

Cheers and thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4):

The structure of StartGlobals (aka BootGlobs) is not publicly documented. However, a widely disseminated leak of System 7.1 source code includes the following definition of the structure in `Internal/Asm/BootEqu.a`. As best I can tell, this information is primarily used in the early boot process and in certain low-level drivers.

```
StartGlobals        RECORD  {sgRamTable},DECR
sgTestSpace         ds.l    2                   ; 2 longs for diagnostics to trash
sgRamTable          equ     *                   ; table of start/size physical RAM, -1 ended
sgMaxChunks         equ     8                   ; maximum # RAM chunks we can accomodate
sgWarmStart         ds.l    1                   ; warm start constant
sgTopOff            ds.l    1                   ; offset to top of boot globals area
sgAllocOff          ds.l    1                   ; offset to bottom of allocated area
sgPhysicalTableOff  ds.l    1                   ; offset to physical space table (for VM et al)
sgTotalRAM          ds.l    1                   ; total RAM in the system
sgPhys2Log          ds.l    1                   ; physical to logical offset for MMU tables
sgMMFlags           ds.b    1                   ; memory manager start mode flags
sgTypeMMU           ds.b    1                   ; type of MMU
sg24Info            ds.b    MMUConfigInfo       ; 24 bit mode MMU info
sg32Info            ds.b    MMUConfigInfo       ; 32 bit mode MMU info
sgRamDiskSize       ds.l    1                   ; size of RAM disk, if any                      <5> rb
sgRamDiskBase       ds.l    1                   ; logical base of RAM disk, if any              <5> rb
sgScratch           ds.l    4                   ; 4 longs of scratch space                      <SM11>
sgEDiskStealFlag    ds.b    1                   ; 1 byte flag to tell INIT code to steal RAM for the EDisk  <SM7>
sgAlign             ds.b    1                   ; alignment
sgBottom            equ     *                   ; last field
                    ENDR
```

The `MMUConfigInfo` structure referenced in `sg24Info` and `sg32Info` is, in turn, defined as follows in `Internal/Asm/MMUEqu.a`:

```
MMUConfigInfo   RECORD  0               ; MMU configuration info
theCRP          ds.l    1               ;    start of the 64-bit CRP on 020/030's           <4>
theSRP          ds.l    1               ;    start of the 32-bit SRP on 040's               <4>
theTC           ds.l    1               ;    the TC (Translation Control Register) value
                                        ;    (the lsw contains the TC on a 68040)           <3>
theTT0          ds.l    1               ;    the {I}TT0 (Transparent Translation Reg 0) value
theTT1          ds.l    1               ;    the {I}TT1 (Transparent Translation Reg 1) value
MMUInfoSize     equ     *-MMUConfigInfo ;    size of an MMU info record
                ENDR
```

Answer (score 2):

Your description leaves me a little confused about the global variables you are actually searching for. Code in the ROM sets up a whole bunch of global values, and these are only sparsely documented.

This archived copy of the [Mac Almanac II](https://archive.fo/thHfG) lists all the global variables. The original source of this information is the Linux/m68k for Mac project.

Comment: The one in Italic, "BootGlobPtr" (@ 0xDDC). It's not documented in the Mac Almanac 2 which ends as 0xDA0...

Comment: In the meantime I learned that in ~1992 they changed the name of BootGlobs into StartGlobals to avoid confusion with BootGlobals (which is indeed another thing).